# Php or Python for Web?

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование

Какой язык на данный момент лучше подходит,например, для написания соц.сети? 
Php или Python?

Comment: А `Ruby`, `Go`, `Java`, `Scala`, `Node.JS` не рассматриваете?

Comment: Нет, не рассматриваю.

Comment: @M3zner ну и зря

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто возьмите несколько социальных сетей и посмотрите на чем они написаны:

- ВКонтакте — PHP.
- Facebook — PHP.
- Twitter — JavaScript, Ruby, Scala и Java.

Другие сети не дают узнать на чем они написаны, но я уверен, что на одна из них не написана на Python.

А вообще нету "лучшего" языка для веба. И у Python, и у PHP есть свои плюсы и минусы.

> Сегодня мы поняли, что PHP и Python довольно сильные конкуренты и
>   сравнивать их лоб в лоб не совсем корректно. Python только недавно
>   начал набирать свою популярность, так как PHP уже много лет служит
>   верностью и правдой для своих разработчиков. Количество вакансий всё
>   время растёт, особенно с тех пор, как появился PHP7. На Python тоже
>   большое количество вакансий, однако если вы живёте не в большом
>   городе, то я советую начать с изучения PHP. Это даст вам возможность
>   быстро найти работу и легко решать проблемы с помощью огромного
>   комъюнити. Однако, если вы уже изучали Python или хотя бы немного
>   знакомы с ним, то определенно начинайте изучать и строить свои первые
>   сайты на Django. Не изучайте теорию, практикуйтесь и учитесь решать
>   поставленые проблемы непосредственно на практике.

[Источник](https://www.make-info.com/php-vs-python/)

Comment: Здесь уместно добавить, что большинство соцсетей, популярных сейчас, начинали писаться ещё в то время, когда питон не был популярен в качестве языка для веба. Поэтому то, что нет известных соцсетей на питоне, ещё ни о чём не говорит. И питон, и PHP одинаково уместны в этом качестве, поэтому автору вопроса стоит брать тупо тот язык, который он лучше знает.

Answer (score 1):

Например, backend Instagram написан на Python, как сказали ранее Python ещё не был популярен в вебе поэтому и писали на PHP. Ещё reddit и pinterest,  если память не изменяет.